# viewpager,recylerview not working if using same fragment for all tabs

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, fragment, fragmentpageradapter

i am using the same fragment for all the tabs.

But the problem is scroll of the recycler view of  fragment working for last tab only.

Recycler view not scrolling for the previous tabs.
Below is my code of the FragmentPagerAdapter:

```
class DataViewPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager?) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {

var fragmentList: MutableList<Fragment> = ArrayList()
var fragmentTitleList: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()

override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
    return DataFragment.newInstance(position)
}

override fun getCount(): Int {
    return 3
}

override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
    return "Deepak"
}
```

}

Here is my code for binding adapter:

```
 var adapter = DataViewPagerAdapter( getChildFragmentManager())

    dataViewpager.adapter = adapter
    dataViewpager.offscreenPageLimit=1
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(dataViewpager)
```

This is code of my fragment:

```
class DataFragment : Fragment() {
lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
companion object {
    fun newInstance(position: Int): DataFragment {
        val fragment = DataFragment()
        val args = Bundle()
        args.putInt("KEY_POSITION", position)
        args.putInt("KEY_ID",1)
        fragment.setArguments(args)
        return fragment
    }
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    var view = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.fragment_data, null)
    recyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView)
    var adapter = DataFragmentAdapter()
    recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(activity, 3)
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    return view;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's related to your problem but `offscreenPageLimit` should be the size of your adapter count.